# Get the pushed ID from child value in Firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to push key based on child id "itemName" and not random key "-MGn8_FVxye1FIEL2ds2"
[My Firebase Inventory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSOFY.png)

```
  public void addInventory(inventoryList inventory, final invenFirebaseHelper.DataStatus dataStatus){
    String key= mReferenceInventory.push().getKey();
    mReferenceInventory.child(key).setValue(inventory)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    dataStatus.DataIsInserted();
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below

```
public void addInventory(inventoryList inventory, final invenFirebaseHelper.DataStatus dataStatus){
    mReferenceInventory.child(inventory.itemName).setValue(inventory)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    dataStatus.DataIsInserted();
                }
            });
}
```

It will saves data with the key given inventory itemName. Make sure it should be unique otherwise which will overrides the existing data.

**Note:** If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127.

Reference this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Comment: But if I update the itemName it won't change and open a create customer child instead. please help

Comment: This is the code 

 public void updateCustomer(String key,customerList customer,final DataStatus dataStatus){
        mReferenceCustomer.child(customer.getCustName()).setValue(customer)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        dataStatus.DataIsUpdated();
                    }
                });
   }